# Editor for corresponding renderer , Check Box Node Tree

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtree

I rendered a check box node tree.
The renderer renders the parent nodes with a (check box + folder like icon ) and the leaf nodes as (Only check box) .

I have rendered it and now i want to make it editable . (i.e) when i click it , the check boxes must be checked and unchecked .

I tried writing an editor . But i am not clear as to how to write it . Please guide me as to how to accomplish this .

Many thanks in advance .

I have built the tree from a Vector . The vector is called NamedVector and it contains Parent node objects . The parent node object holds the leaf nodes . The leaf nodes are of type CheckBoxNode.

```
public class CheckBoxNodeRenderer  implements TreeCellRenderer{
NonLeafRenderer nonLeafRenderer = new NonLeafRenderer();
protected JCheckBox check;
protected JLabel label;
public JPanel panel;
CheckBoxNode checkNode;
public JCheckBox getLeafRenderer()
{
    return leafRenderer;
}
public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() 
{
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    check = new JCheckBox();
    label = new JLabel();
    Font fontValue;
    fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
    if (fontValue != null) {
        leafRenderer.setFont(fontValue);
    }
    Boolean booleanValue = (Boolean) UIManager
    .get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
    leafRenderer.setFocusPainted((booleanValue != null)
            && (booleanValue.booleanValue()));
    selectionBorderColor = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBorderColor");
    selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
    selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
    textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
    textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
}

///////////////////
/**
 * Approach by returning a panel . 
 */
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean expanded,
        boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            String stringValue = tree.convertValueToText(value, isSelected,
                    expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
                    panel.setEnabled(true);
                    if(leaf){
                        if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;


                        checkNode = (CheckBoxNode)node.getUserObject();
                        check.setSelected(checkNode.isSelected());
                        label.setFont(tree.getFont());
                        label.setText(value.toString());
                        label.setIcon(null);
                        panel.removeAll();
                        panel.add(check,BorderLayout.WEST);
                        panel.add(label);
                        panel.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    }


else if(!leaf){
            if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) ) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;

            Object parent = (Object)node.getUserObject();
            System.err.println(parent.toString());

            NamedVector parentNode = (NamedVector) parent;
            check.setSelected(parentNode.isSelected());
            label.setFont(tree.getFont());
            label.setText(parentNode.toString());
            label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("Tree.openIcon"));
            panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(check,BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setVisible(true);
            }
        } 
        return panel;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not listening for the events.  In your getTreeCellRendererComponent method, create a listener and then make sure to tell the tree model that you've changed a node via the nodeChanged method.  The following should work (you might have to make some variables final to use them in the inner class though):

```
check.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
    checkNode.setSelected(check.isSelected());
    DefaultTreeModel dtm = (DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel();
    dtm.nodeChanged(node);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried extending the DefaultTreeCellRenderer?  I normally do that rather than implement the TreeCellRenderer interface, gives you a lot for free.  I basically do something very similar to what you have and it works for me.  The subclass vs. interface is the only difference really.

Comment: But the defaultTreeCellRenderer renders the parent node just as an icon . I want both the check box and the icon for the parent nodes . Thats the reason i went for a custom renderer.

Comment: But you've implemented the getTreeCellRendererComponent() method so your code will render it.

Comment: Extended the Default Tree Cell Renderer . That gives no effect too here .

Comment: I achieved it by setting the listener to the entire tree and getting the node at the point of the click and then handling it . :-)

Comment: -1 for suggestion a listener in a _renderer_ - that's simply the-wrong-thing-todo and doesn't work at all: renderers are completely passive and not part of the container hierarchy at any time

Comment: I achieved by rendering it by my specifications and outside the renderer i set up the listener .